# Can a framework like Redux-Saga achieve the same without use of generators? If not, why not?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, generator, redux-saga

I am designing the API of a business-logic library. It is similar in goals and approach to Redux-Saga - managing side-effects and change-propagation of a central store while eliminating any Redux or React dependency.

Can anyone detail specific benefits that means redux-saga has to use generators rather than, for example, offering decorators for async functions (that would intercept callArguments and returnValues and make them available for middleware). I need to decide what strategy to use.

Redux-Saga uses synchronous generator functions declared with `*` and using `yield` to define business logic. This is in contrast to code for side-effects composed from asynchronous Promise-based functions declared with `async` and using `await`.

In https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/987 Mateusz Burzyński the maintainer of redux-saga states ‘redux-saga cannot be rewritten to async/await’. He goes on ‘Saga being an interpreter of effects is granting us the full control of how and when those effects are resolved’ and ‘we just can't use anything other than generators to reach our goals, because only them are giving us the needed flexibility’.

However, I believe that wrapping async calls could also allow interception of how and when async calls were resolved. I ask myself what did he mean?

So far I have modelled my logic-layer’s ‘sagas’ on the generator-based approach of Redux-Saga and I'm fairly happy with it. However developer feedback so far is basically ‘why are you using yield not await?’ (this is from non redux-saga users who might complain also about redux-saga).

Their view has been that using `yield` alienates developers who find generators to be unfamiliar magic compared to `async/await` code, so I find myself having to justify the approach and sometimes I struggle.

Functions based on either `await` or `yield` have a lot in common. In each case steps can be run strictly in sequence, they can delegate to other functions, they ‘pause’ while they wait for the next event and they keep implicit state according to where they are ‘up to’ within the sequential procedure, without having to define any additional state to manage this. I am finding it difficult to articulate clearly what CANNOT be expressed through `await` and CAN ONLY be expressed through `yield` to justify the initial alignment of my API with redux-saga and generators. Is there anything I can say to justify it?

Under the hood the primitives in my framework already provide async-based implementations for editing and tracking changes in the store (eliminating Redux reducers and redux-saga middleware) and for event queues (fulfilling the need for action-consume patterns like channels and takeLatest). However, the async operations I’ve written have then been wrapped again in ‘Actions’ to present them in the generator layer. This makes me speculate that the generator layer isn’t buying me anything compared to just writing functions using async that directly invoke my async layers. Is there's something fundamental I'm missing?

I am beginning to doubt myself and would like to know others’ views why Redux-Saga uses yield, or what particular power is available through a generator approach as opposed to just writing wrappers around async calls.

So far I can think of two main reasons, which seem weak, given `yield` might alienate many mainstream developers, and assuming async can deliver the same goodness.

- Synchronous generator code makes business logic tests easier to write
  and problem cases easier to log for debugging. You can emulate all
  kinds of events and side-effects without mocking (see
  redux-saga-test-plan) since you can intercept every instruction and
  substitute every value arising! Having said this, mocking is a really
  mature and familiar technique for javascript test authors. Also if
  the framework introduced wrappers to intercept the core async functions of
  your app, this interception could be used for mocking and logging in any
  case.
- Forcing developers to write logic through synchronous
  generators creates an artificial barrier to isolate it from async
  code. You can’t even use the async keyword in a saga. Perhaps this
  would make people write better business logic separation? Having said
  this, if we accepted that ‘wild-west’ async code was a legitimate
  starting point, we could progressively introduce the power of sagas
  by just wrapping selected async calls for interception, until we had
  the level of interception we actually need. E.g. our processes could
  block on `await actionMatching()` or `await selectorChange()` to be notified of
  the initiation or completion of another call in another 'process' or to notice a state
  transition. This wouldn't need events served up through a generator to enable
  processes to block on `yield takeLatest()`.

Is there a fundamental constraint that means I need generators to fulfil the capabilities of Redux-Saga?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux Saga cannot be re-written to use `async/await` as per the developers of the library - or maybe more accurately, in my understanding, it would be so onerous for the developers of such a library that it's never going to happen.

> From the library's (redux-saga) point of view async/await is to generators like a younger, dummy brother wink You can do much, much more with generators than with async/await. -- [Source comment](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1373#issuecomment-375580875)

and

> `redux-saga` cannot be rewritten to async/await - that uses Promises and its way harder to coordinate 'parallel' tasks with those. It would also mean a big change in semantics, how things actually work. In example `select` effect is synchronous - cant achieve that with Promises.

> Saga being an interpreter of effects is granting us the full control of how and when those effects are resolved + effects are just simple object which are easily comparable and can be monitored which is also way harder with Promises.
> -- [Source comment](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/987#issuecomment-301039792)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Slbox! From my endless experiments working on a runner (and time-travel generator framework) for @lauf/store I have concluded the same thing. The simplest statement I can find of the problem is something like `You can't unpromise a Promise`. In a framework like redux-saga the generator returns a _description_ of the promise it will run rather than invoking anything, and many other things are possible from there, such as e.g. tests which verify pure business logic (no need to mock if you use https://github.com/jfairbank/redux-saga-test-plan).

Comment: An async approach seems possible in theory, so long as you respect the need for the runner framework to actually _invoke_ everything async, e.g. `await runFn(asyncFn, arg1, arg2, arg3)` but that's a different scheme and may open up its own problems. Having synchronous generators means some of these constraints are imposed _by the language_ which is probably the best place for them.